# Xamarin UWP Visual Asset Generator - Can I use it for any images I use within my application?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-store-apps

I'm using Xamarin forms and I'm wondering, does the UWP Visual Asset Generator work for any image you want to add to your apps XAML?  The documentation found [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos) is really confusing.  It appears as though the asset generator is only for assets that the app needs by default.  If you try to use it to add a general image to your app it tries to overwrite the icons your app needs for windows tiles and the application icon, etc.

I have seen others on SO say that all you need to do is manually add the image to your Assets/ folder and while I can easily do that, you don't get all the different sizes and scale factor images that the Visual Asset Generator creates.

I did try using the Visual Asset Generator to create a new image anyway using the "App Icon" option but I made sure to use a different name so it didn't overwrite my existing app icon.  Well, even though it didn't overwrite my original app icon my app is now using the image I'm trying to use within my app as the app icon as well.

Anyway, I called this new image I added from my XAML but instead of xaml pulling the best looking image based on the size of my image property which was 300x300 it instead used one of the really small images and it was really blurry so I'm not sure this is worth using anyway but some clarification would help in case I'm missing something.

Comment: [Preferred format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterR.UWPVisualAssetsGenerator) is SVG because it's a vector format and has no problems with scaling. The logo should be square and should have no additional space around it. You could use Inkscape (Freeware) or Adobe Illustrator to create a logo.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew I know how to use Visual Asset Generator and I know how to create images and I already use it to create application icons, tiles and splash screens.  My question is regarding using it for other image within your app like for instance, lets say I want an image embedded in the 2nd page of my app, can I use VAG to create this image?  ... I'm starting to think this isn't the purpose of VAG but it should be.  It should allow you to create ancillary images for your app so the best scaled image is picked automatically for you within your app.

Comment: @Helzgate so for images in general, what did you end up using for asset generation for UWP?

Comment: @MarkZhukovsky I just used the highest resolution PNG image I would need for my UWP project and placed it in my assets folder and moved on.

Comment: @helzgate ty for response - yea i use a similar approach - xxxhdpi from android I save as .scale-400 in UWP and don't bother generating the 200 or base 100 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is regarding using it for other image within your app like for instance, lets say I want an image embedded in the 2nd page of my app

These images are not generated for use during app development.

Images generated by UWP Visual Assets Generator are used as the logos or icons of an app in different devices or scenes for different sizes needs. These images are generated for the process of publishing instead of developing the app.Therefore,making good use of these images is of great help for users to identify your app.

Explain with the generated pictures **Square44x44Logo.png** and **Square150x150Logo.png**:

[image]